# Models for which Measurable implies Universally Baire?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

To begin, Universally Baire sets are Lebesgue measurable (slide 4 of http://www.ub.edu/RSTR2018/slides/Woodin.pdf). I was wondering if there are any natural models of ZFC
where the converse holds, and sets are Universally Baire iff they're Lebesgue measurable. (It can't be ZF set theory because I am fairly sure that models such as the Solovay Model have all sets having both properties, due to determinacy)

Comment: The Solovay model is indeed one where all sets of reals have nice regularity properties (e.g. Baire measurable, Lebesgue measurable, etc.) but it is not a model of determinacy. What is true, however, is that "the most natural" models of AD are of the form $L(\Bbb R)$, which can be seen as *a Solovay-type* model. But it's certainly not "the Solovay model".

Comment: The only way to have all Lebesgue measurable sets be universally Baire is to have all sets be Lebesgue measurable.  The reason is that all subsets of the standard Cantor set (in $\mathbb R$) are Lebesgue measurable, since they have measure zero. So they'd all be universally Baire. But "universally Baire" is preserved by homeomorphism, so all subsets of $2^\omega$ would be universally Baire, hence measurable (for the product measure).